# Why do we need word get in String

Tags: kotlin

**My expectation:**
I want to see something like that:

```
package com.example.myapplication
class ExampleGet {
    val p2: String = "Black"
}

fun main(){
    var ex = ExampleGet()
    println(ex.p2)
}
```

I understand this example, it's work fine.

**My problem**

I don't know why do we need a word get in this class

```
package com.example.myapplication

class ExampleGet {
    val p: String get() = "Black"
    val p2: String = "Black"
}

fun main(){
    var ex = ExampleGet()
    println(ex.p)
    println(ex.p2)
    println(ex.p==ex.p2)
}
```

But I don't know what's difference between
Line 1

```
val p: String get() = "Black"
```

and
Line 2

```
val p2: String = "Black"
```

If we don't have any difference between Line 1 and Line 2 why do get() exist in kotlin? I ask because I have fond an example

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.FragmentThirdBinding

class ThirdFragment:Fragment() {
private var _binding : FragmentThirdBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
}
```

I don't know why did people use

```
 private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

but not

```
private val binding = _binding!!
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **both lines define a property, but one has an initialiser while the other overrides the getter method.**

In Kotlin, a property always has a getter method (and, if it's mutable, a setter method). When you refer to the property (e.g. `myExampleGet.p`), you're actually calling the getter method. (This is unlike Java.) A property will usually (though not always) have a private field to store the value, as well (known as the ‘backing field’).

Let's take your two cases in reverse order. **Your second case has an initialiser**, which is the most common form:

```
val p2: String = "Black"
```

This defines a property called `p2`, of type `String`, and assigns it the initial value `"Black"`. You don't specify a setter method, so you get the default one, which just returns the backing field.

**Your first case provides a setter method**, instead of an initialiser:

```
val p: String get() = "Black"
```

This says that `p` is a property with type `String`, and that its getter method always returns the hard-coded value `"Black"`.

This property doesn't need a backing field, because it would never be used.

So, what's the difference? In your example, very little. The main one is that **every instance of `ExampleGet` has a field called `p2`**, all of which contain the same reference (to the hard-coded string); they do *not* have a field `p`. So `p` is more memory-efficient.

However, in other situations, the difference is much less subtle! For example, the setter might not return a constant value, e.g.:

```
class ExampleGet {
    val p: String get() = (++counter).toString()
    val p2: String = (++counter).toString()

    private var counter = 0
}
```

Here `p2` would always have the same value it was initialised with (probably `"1"`), while **`p` would give a different value each time**: `"2"`, then `"3"`, then `"4"`, and so on. (In practice, such a getter might perform some calculation on another property, or get it from some other source, but I hope this illustrates the point.)

Another situation making the difference obvious would be if the properties were mutable, i.e. `var` instead of `val`:

```
class ExampleGet {
    var p: String get() = "Black"
    var p2: String = "Black"
}
```

Here `p2` would behave as you expect, returning the value you set:

```
val eg = ExampleGet()
println(eg.p2) // prints "Black"
eg.p2 = "White"
println(eg.p2) // prints "White"
```

But **`p` would always return the same value**:

```
eg.p = "White"
println(eg.p) // prints "Black"
```

(I think `p` would have a backing field in this case, which would store whatever value you set — but you'd never be able to see that value, because the setter would always return the hard-coded value.)

So the two cases are doing very different things, even though the effect is practically the same in the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Properties in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html) can have an initializer, a getter, and a setter, but all of them are optional.
When you write

```
val p2: String = "black"
```

the property `p2` is initialized with value "black". It has an implicit getter that always returns the current value of the property, and it would have an implicit setter that sets that value, if it was a `var` and not a `val`.

When you write

```
val p: String get() = "black"
```

you defined an explicit getter for the property `p` that always returns "black". So, in this example it does not become clear what the difference is, because "black" is a constant value.

Let's consider instead the following example:

```
val p1 : String = System.nanoTime()
val p2 : String get() = System.nanoTime()
```

When you use property `p1`, it will always return the time in nanoseconds of the moment it was initialized.

However, when you use property `p2`, it will always return the time in nanoseconds of the moment, you are calling `p2`.

So, regarding your example with the property `binding`, the definition with getter instead of an initializer, allows to always get the value of the internal variable `_binding` instead of only its initial value. The variable `_binding` is called a [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties).

Comment: Although the difference is not clear as you mentioned, the behavior between `p2` and `p` is different. `p2` has a backing field so it will make the class use slightly more memory per instance to store a reference to the constant String.

Answer (score 0):

The difference you can see in decompiled Kotlin into Java code
So the code:

```
class ExampleGet {
    val p: String get() = "Black"
    val p2: String = "Black"
}
```

Become (Java):

```
public final class ExampleGet {
   @NotNull
   private final String p2 = "Black";

   @NotNull
   public final String getP() {
      return "Black";
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getP2() {
      return this.p2;
   }
}
```

As you can see, val with get() become method returning value.

In my practice, I use variable shadowing to make user's code operate with different type, for example:

```
val publicValue: List<String>
    get() = _privateValue
private val _privateValue: MutableList<String>...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been covered, but specifically for this stuff in your example:

```
private var _binding : FragmentThirdBinding? = null
private val binding: FragmentThirdBinding get() = _binding!!
```

I've been explicit about the types here - `_binding` is **nullable**, `binding` is **non-null**. `binding` is a getter that's casting the value of `_binding` to another type (the non-null equivalent). When people access `binding`, they "don't have to worry" about it being null, don't have to do any null handling etc.

Here's the thing - none of that makes any sense. It's only non-null because they've asserted that with the `!!` operator (which should generally be seen as a red flag - it's circumventing the nullability checker, telling it it's wrong).

What they're *probably* doing is assigning `binding` later (e.g. in `onCreate`), but the variable needs to be initialised to *something* before that, so they make it nullable and set it to null as a placeholder. But that makes `binding` nullable, and it needs to be null-checked every time, even if in reality, it will *always* have been assigned to something by then, and will never be null when something tries to use it.

So this solution creates another placeholder variable, called `_binding`, which *is* nullable. But the code accesses `binding` instead, which is non-null. It's all based on the idea that `_binding` definitely won't be null when accessed, so the `!!` will always be valid.

---

This situation is what `lateinit` is for though:

```
lateinit var binding: FragmentThirdBinding
```

Same thing - a promise to assign it before it's read, no need for nullability. It's a `var` instead of a `val` but that's rarely going to matter, and not for something like this where you're only going to set it once anyway. To me it's more readable, uses the language features instead of working around them (`!!`), etc.

I'm not sure where the "cast a nullable field" pattern came from, it looks a lot like the way you're recommended to expose a private `MutableLiveData` as a public immutable `LiveData` type instead, so I'm not sure if people are just adapting that. Maybe there's a benefit to it I don't know about!